# Getting a network error on my first NextJS / React Application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mern

I am building my first NextJS app on a MERN stack, and when I run NPM run dev i get the following error that is constantly running in my network tab in console.'

Right now, my application is just 3 basic pages. With 3 Routes in Next, otherwise there is no other content.

On the pages is literally just "Page 1", "Page 2" and "Page 3"

```
EventSource's response has a MIME type ("application/json") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.
```

When i inspect one of the elements in the network tab, this is what I see

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr?page=/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,Cache-Control,X-Accel-Buffering,Connection,Date,Transfer-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, CONNECT, OPTIONS, TRACE, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type, Cache-Control, X-Accel-Buffering, Connection, Date, Transfer-Encoding
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-transform
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/event-stream;charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 20 May 2020 14:48:11 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Accel-Buffering: no
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Accept: text/event-stream
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36
page: /
```

I dont know how to get rid of this, and searching does not seem to help.

Comment: Which version of next.js do you have? Are you using EventSources yourself?

Comment: I am using version 9.0.2, and i am not using anything. I started the project, built 3 pages and just happened to look at my console and then spent a few hours trying to figure it out to no avail.

Comment: did you ever found what was your issue ?